# How should I set the scaleType of an ImageView, when I use Glide

Tags: android, imageview, android-glide, scaletype

I use Glide for image loading. Now I want to set the `scaleType` of an image to `centerCrop`.

There are 2 ways of which I know of doing it:
1. By setting the `scaleType` attribute of the `ImageView` to `centerCrop` in the layout
2. By using Glide calling `GlideApp.centerCrop()`

The optical results of both ways are identical.

**Now my Question is**: Does it make a considerable difference, which way I choose, maybe regarding performance or quality or else?